# Aggregation on the basis of the set of nested docs

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have the next 5 docs:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "student" : "Oscar", "courses" : [ "A", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "student" : "Alan", "courses" : [ "A", "B", "C" ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "student" : "Kate", "courses" : [ "A", "B", "D" ] }
{ "_id" : "4", "student" : "John", "courses" : [ "A", "B", "C" ] }
{ "_id" : "5", "student" : "Bema", "courses" : [ "A", "B" ] }
```

**I want to manipulate the collection so that it will return a group of  students (with their _id) by set (combination) of courses they take and calculate how many students in each set.**

In the example above I have 3 set (combination) of courses and number of students as below:

1 - `[ "A", "B" ]`      <- 2 students take this combination

2 - `[ "A", "B", "C" ]` <- 2 students

3 - `[ "A", "B", "D" ]`   <- 1 student

I feel like this is more like `MapReduce` task rather than `Aggregation`...not sure...

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks a lot to @ExplosionPills

So the following aggregation command:

```
db.students.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        _id: "$courses",
        count: {$sum: 1},
    students: {$push: "$_id"}
    }
}])
```

gives me the following output:

```
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B", "D" ], "count" : 1, "students" : [ "3" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "count" : 2, "students" : [ "2", "4" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B" ], "count" : 2, "students" : [ "1", "5" ] }
```

It groups by set of courses, counts number of students belong to it and their `_id`s.

**UPDATE 2**

I found out, the aggregation above treats combination `[ "C", "A", "B" ]` as different from `[ "A", "B", "C" ]`. But I need these 2 count as same.

So let's look at the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : "1", "student" : "Oscar", "courses" : [ "A", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "2", "student" : "Alan", "courses" : [ "A", "B", "C" ] }
{ "_id" : "3", "student" : "Kate", "courses" : [ "A", "B", "D" ] }
{ "_id" : "4", "student" : "John", "courses" : [ "A", "B", "C" ] }
{ "_id" : "5", "student" : "Bema", "courses" : [ "A", "B" ] }
{ "_id" : "6", "student" : "Alex", "courses" : [ "C", "A", "B" ] }
```

Let's see this in output:

```
{ "_id" : [ "C", "A", "B" ], "count" : 1, "students" : [ "6" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B", "D" ], "count" : 1, "students" : [ "3" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "count" : 2, "students" : [ "2", "4" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B" ], "count" : 2, "students" : [ "1", "5" ] }
```

See the lines 1 and 3 - this is not what I wanted.

So, to treat `[ "C", "A", "B" ]` and `[ "A", "B", "C" ]` as same combination I changed the aggregation as follows:

```
db.students.aggregate([
    {$unwind: "$courses" },
    {$sort : {"courses": 1}}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$_id", courses: {$push: "$courses"}}}, 
    {$group: {_id: "$courses", count: {$sum:1}, students: {$push: "$_id"}}}
    ])
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B", "D" ], "count" : 1, "students" : [ "3" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B" ], "count" : 2, "students" : [ "5", "1" ] }
{ "_id" : [ "A", "B", "C" ], "count" : 3, "students" : [ "6", "4", "2" ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an aggregate operation using grouping.

```
db.students.aggregate([{
    $group: {
        // Uniquely identify the document.
        // The $ syntax queries on this field
        _id: "$courses",

        // Add 1 for each field found (effectively a counter)
        count: {$sum: 1}
    }
}]);
```

EDIT:

If the courses can be in any order, you can `$unwind`, `$sort`, and `$group` again as suggested in the edited question.  It's also possible to do this via `mapReduce`, but I'm not sure which is faster.

```
db.students.mapReduce(
    function () {
        // Use the sorted courses as the key
        emit(this.courses.sort(), this._id);
    },
    function (key, values) {
        return {"students": values, count: values.length};
    },
    {out: {inline: 1}}
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to output a list of students' `_id`s as a nested attribute for each group?

Comment: You could add another grouping like `students: {$push: "$_id"}`

Comment: It seems it's grouping on the basis of how elements ordered in `courses`.
For example, if there's a record `{ "_id" : "6", "student" : "Alan", "courses" : [ "C", "B", "A" ] }`, it's treated as different combination. Now, I think I will need to do sorting first and then only grouping...

Comment: @oscar awesome thanks for sharing your find. I'll take a look too and update my answer.